# Вложенный запрос не предварен EXISTS

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы tab1 и tab2.

```
tab1  | содержит информацию о мотоциклах
---------------------
motID | идентификатор
Name  | наименование
```

Таблица tab2

```
tab2  | содержит информацию о водителях
--------------------------------
ID    | идентификатор
motID | идентификатор мотоцикла
FIO   | имя водителя
```

Мне необходимо вывести информацию о мотоциклах с количеством цилиндров в движке больше 4 И на которых (мотоциклах) ездят 3 или больше человек. Что я делаю не так?

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.motID = tab2.motID 
WHERE
Count > 4
AND
(SELECT COUNT(Name) AS [DriversCount] FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.motID = tab2.motID GROUP BY tab1.motID) >= 3 --- Здесь я сделал join еще раз для отдельной проверки работы запроса
```

Comment: Опишите структуру БД, относящуюся к вопросу. Дополните вопрос ошибкой, которая у вас возникает. Или же входными данными и данные, которые хотите увидеть, если ошибок не возникает, но вы получаете неверный результат

Comment: Есть 2 таблицы tab1 и tab2. Tab1 содержит информацию о мотоциклах: идентификатор motID и наименование, tab2 содержит собственный идентификатор ID, motID и имя владельца. Связь между таблицами по motID, в примере я это не указал, т.к. посчитал это необязательным моментом. Информацию которую я хочу получить следующая: получение на выходе записей об мотоциклах с количеством цилиндров в движке больше 4 и на которых ездят 3 или более человек. Ошибка возникает следующая: Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Это запрещено

Comment: Отредактируйте [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/873489/edit) ваш вопрос. Не нужно писать такие вещи в комментарии. Нужно всё красиво оформить

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос, извините.

Answer (score 1):

Обращайте внимание на ошибку, которую вам выдает sql. По ней можно понять, что вы делаете не так.

Собственно, в данном случае подзапрос делает группировку по `ID` мотоцикла, и для каждого из них возвращает свое скалярное значение `COUNT`. В итоге результат запроса - массив значений, которое вы сравниваете с числом.

Попробуйте почитать про [предложение HAVING](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_having_clause.html)

Запрос, вероятно, должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
SELECT tab1.*
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.motID = tab2.motID 
WHERE
Count > 4
GROUP BY tab1.motID
HAVING COUNT(tab1.motID) >= 3
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал Ваш вариант, но он у меня не работает.
Ошибка: Столбец "Tab1.Name" недопустим в списке выбора, поскольку он не содержится ни в агрегатной  функции, ни в предложении GROUP BY.

Такой вариант тоже не работает, однако, запрос после AND выдает нужную мне информацию

`SELECT *
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.motID = tab2.motID 
WHERE
Count > 4
AND
(SELECT COUNT(tab1.motID)
FROM tab1 JOIN tab2
ON tab1.motID = tab2.motID
GROUP BY tab1.motID
HAVING COUNT(tab1.motID) >= 3)`

Ошибка: Рядом с ")" в контексте, где ожидается условие , указано выражение типа, отлич. от лог.

Comment: Спасибо, перешел по Вашей ссылке и разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(tab2.motID) AS [DriverCount]
FROM tab1
JOIN tab2 ON tab1.motID = tab2.motID
WHERE Count > 4
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(Drivers.CarID) >= 3
```